# How are notifications removed on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

I had a couple of notifications on my lock screen on my iPhone, some Facebook, and some SMS.  I was logged into Facebook on my PC, and saw the notifications there also, so used my desktop to see what they were.  Then my phone screen lit up again, and on the lock screen were no new notifications, but the Facebook ones were gone, leaving just the previous SMS ones.  Is there now functionality to remove and/or sync notifications across devices?  I note that on my desktop I seem to see repeat notifications appear that I have already dismissed on my iPhone, so perhaps it's only iOS that supports is as yet?  Can someone describe the mechanisms used to remove such notifications from my phone?

Comment: would reading this interest you ? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Comment: Possibly, thanks. I'll look later, but I was hoping for a laymans explanation; I thought notifications were a simple push operation, but apparently not any more

Comment: Well they are but : If the app is running, it gets the notification immediately. If the app isn't running, the notification is held in the phone to be consumed at the app's next launch. If the iPhone is offline when the sender attempts delivery, APNS attempts to send the notification for 28 days.